# Configure IIS for Exchange Management Console

Tags: iis, iis-7, exchange, exchange-2010, iis-7.5

I'am newbie to IIS and Exchange Server, and I did not know that Exchange Management Console and Exchange Management Shell use IIS, so I removed IIS from my mail server. Now we get emails and we can send emails, but we can not start the Exchange Management Console or Exchange Management Shell to add or edit users and so on.

I get the following error message when I try to start it:

[image] (Click to enlarge)

I have searched the internet, and what is clear is that IIS is necessary for Exchange Management Console or Exchange Management Shell to work. And there is a problem with Kerberos authentication.

So I re-installed IIS but things still not work, so the default config is not enough.

I have searched for the solution in last 3 days and have tried out some promising solutions but have not succeeded. I'm new to this things so I dare not do everything what I read, because it could break the things down more heavily.

So I really appreciate if someone could write down to me how I should configure the default site or one new site in IIS to work properly with Exchange Management Console and Exchange Management Shell step from step.

Additional info: Server run on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Exchange version is 2010 and IIS version is 7.5

**UPDATE**: Due to the character restriction of comments I reply here:

I got always the same error in Server Management when I try to add bindings to the default site (any protocol) The error message: The World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW Service) did not register the URL prefix %1 for site %2. The site has been disabled. The data field contains the error number.

The support page of this error: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30eb8114-5a0d-4bd7-bd99-fa5a8df7e3ca.aspx

And I fount in the Events the detailed error of the problem. ( They comes since I uninstalled IIS)

> An unexpected failure has occurred. The problem will require administrator intervention. The service will retry in 15 minutes. Diagnostic information:
>    a következő helyen: ( "a következő helyen" in english looks like: at the this place)   Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Metabase.IisUtility.CreateIISDirectoryEntry(String iisDirectoryEntryPath, TaskErrorLoggingReThrowDelegate writeError, Object identity, Boolean reThrow)
>      a következő helyen: ( "a következő helyen" in english looks like: at the this place) Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Metabase.IisUtility.FindWebObject(String parent, String name, String type)
>      a következő helyen: ( "a következő helyen" in english looks like: at the this place) Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Metabase.IisUtility.FindWebDirObject(String parent, String name)
>      a következő helyen: Microsoft.Exchange.Servicelets.RPCHTTP.Servicelet.FindIISVDir()
>      a következő helyen: Microsoft.Exchange.Servicelets.RPCHTTP.Servicelet.Work()
>   An error occurred while trying to access the IIS metabase. Make sure that the IIS Manager is installed and configured correctly.

So this look like the the root of the problem, but I still don't know how to resolve it. 
I read that IIS Virtual Directories recreation is needed but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you list the event errors you get as well when this happens?  Both Application and System if there are any in System.  It's probably going to require editing some files here: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config.  You may also have to recreate the IIS Virtual Directories.  Never seen someone do this to be honest, but will try to help.

Comment: I updated the description. I read about that the IIS Virtual Directories recreataion is needed but I dont know how to do it. Could you explain how I should do that?

Comment: When you reinstalled IIS, which features did you check/include?  Was IIS6 Compatibility included?  Also follow this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691354%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx - even though it is for Exc2007 it should still apply.  Let me know.

Comment: 1. If you don't know the system, don't touch it. 2. Know when to call the vendor for support. This is the time you should be opening a support case with Microsoft.

Comment: editing comment at this time...

Comment: Sorry for first comment. I could not edit anymore.

I still could not solve the error, but an another chance is come to solve the problem. We backup our server every month, so we have now a backup which is the one with working configuration.

The save include (I try to translate it because we use the server in hungarian) Restoring without operating system, system status, Reserved for system, Local (C:), SVRDATA(D:)

My question is this: will it work if I make a restore? Sadly we dont back up the operating system so maybe it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I try to answer my question, I have restored our servers with a full backup, so the server is working now and I see the settings in the IIS. Therefore I try to write down all the settings here because the bad and missing settins after reinstall was which create the error.

There is one site called Default Web Site with

- ID: 1
- Binding:    **Type**,    **Host Name**,   **Port**,   **IP Address**,    **Binding** 
  http (none) 80 * (none)
  https (none) 443 (none) (none)
  http (none) 80 127.0.0.1 (none)
  https (none) 443 127.0.0.1 (none)  - [**image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35QnX.png)
  net.tcp (none) (none) (none) 808:*
  net.pipe (none) (none) (none) *
  net.msmq (none) (none) (none) localhost
  msmq.formatname (none) (none) (none) *
- Path: %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot

The https connections has SSL-certificates which is Microsoft Exchange (not trusted certificate, the creator is the server itself.)

This is just the settings of the Default webpage bu there are tons of other sub pages (for example: /autodiscover) and settings which I could not write down (too many).

Maybe it post will solve your similar problem, and Exchange could connect to create this things, but if not work the only solution is really a full reinstall of system.

[Just a part of the tons of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwUTq.png). If the correctly set basic settings did not help you then unnecessary to attempt to start the restore, you cant set all the settings manually.

Comment: I set my answer as correct, because it is contain the most importatn things and basic settins for working configuration in on place, however Daniel Dainty and Pauby also mention that the repairing of Exchange is nearly impossible. Thanks for them help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Would reinstalling Exchange be out of the question here? I think you would be better off doing that if at all possible. It may also be advantageous to open a Microsoft support case, if you have a license which enables you to do so.

Comment: Years of email conversations is on the server, so reinstalling is the last-last thing what I want to do. We don't have support unfortunately. :( 

Could I reinstall the Exhange without lost all the conversations and email accounts if I can't acces the Exchange MC and Shell? And whatsmore this email account belongs to users in our local domain, so after reinstalling I should bind them back to there owners. It is a harder way than the repairing I think.

Comment: Understood. How about build a new server, migrate the mailboxes, rebuild the faulty one, migrate back? Fairly non-disruptive... mind you, I'm not sure if the lack of an IIS connection would permit your destination server from communicating with its source. I've not seen this scenario before to be honest!

Comment: I still prefer repairing. As I wrote I am newbie to this things as Install, configure, backup from old, migrate, reinstall, reconfigure, migrate again will cause a lot more problem so I think try to repair the configuration is a better way. So this is the last-last - 1 solution. And getting the answers to that lot of problem what i will be create more painful than asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

Reparing a broken IIS setup in Exchange a huge PITA and I've never yet managed to do it (nor have I come across your situation). Even copying settings and configs from working servers doesn't fix it.

You have two options as I see it:

1. As has been suggested, migrating to a new server, fixing the broken one and migrating back, if possible. I'm dubious this will work with a broken IIS.
2. Contact Microsoft and raise a support case.

Comment: Thats sounds bad. I will still try to find the solution for few days. If I have not succeed, I will do the migrating. But how could I migrate if I dont have access to the Managment Console and Shell??

Comment: You would have access using the new server you install.

Comment: How could I migrate? I can't access the admin panel So I could not export anything (nor console). Do you have any idea how I could make it?